# EWMA covariance using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement in R the covariance function for the Exponential Weighted Moving Average (EWMA) model, given by:

Cov(x,y;t+1) = lambda * Cov(x,y;t) + (1-lambda) * r(x;t) * r(y;t)

for t=1,2,...,n.

I have the following code:

```
ewma.cov <- function(v1,v2,lambda) {
     n <- length(v1)
     cv <- double()
     cv[1] <- 0
     for(i in 1:n)
         cv[i+1] <- cv[i]*lambda + (1-lambda)*v1[i]*v2[i]
     cv
}
```

However, something goes wrong when I call the function since I get the following error:

> Error in cv[i] * lambda : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Please consider to add the call to your function.

Comment: Further to Pascal's note, I can't make it go wrong. `ewma.cov(runif(10),runif(10),.4)` returns values okay - how are you calling it?

Comment: I was using as argument of v2 a data.frame instead of a vector, that's why it didn't work. Thanks.